# Merge cards in Trello?

Tags: trello

In capturing requirements from a user, I recorded information on two cards for a requested report, and then realized that the user (just due to a lack of technical knowledge, which the user shouldn't have to have) requested separate reports for something that was far easier to process in one report.

Now that I have two cards and have information recorded in each card, I'd like to merge the data from the (essentially duplicated) card onto the other. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aside from manual editing, I don't believe that this is possible right now. It's also not currently on the [the Trello Development Board](https://trello.com/board/trello-development/4d5ea62fd76aa1136000000c).

As it's a small number of cards, you're probably best off combining them manually.

Comment: Not so easy when the cards contain checklists though!

Comment: Or a bunch of comments.

Comment: Or votes. One of the more difficult things to handle manually.

Comment: Or attachments.

Answer (score 16):

My approach is to:

1. pick one of the cards as the master
2. copy as much info as you practically can (or want to)
3. paste the URL of the other card into the comments of the master
4. archive the unwanted card.

You can still access the info from the archived card if needed, it is not deleted.

Comment: linking and archiving works great for me.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can click CHECKLIST on the right and click "copy checklist from" to get your checklists.  Of course they won't be checked off if you have any checked off.

As for comments, all I know about now is the copy and paste feature.